# Adding a while True: to a file that gets live stock data every 5 seconds in Python

Tags: python

This code correctly gets a live quote from Interactive Brokers, and then sends it to a csv text file with the current price. Now, how do I make this code automatically keep running? I am doing a sleep command every 15 seconds.

```
import csv
from ib_insync import *

stocks = ['TVIX']
test = list()

for stock in stocks:
    stock = Stock(stock, 'SMART','USD')
    contract = ib.qualifyContracts(stock)
    test.append(ib.reqMktData(contract[0],snapshot=True))
    ib.sleep(15)

for stock in test:
    f = open('tvix-price.csv','w')
    f.write(str(stock.last))

    f.close()
```

Below is my code of what I have so far...
 I get no errors which is kind of strange. Nothing at all happens. I will attempt to restart my Kernal to make sure I am connected.

On second thought, is doing a while True even the best method?

```
while True:

    stocks = ['TVIX']
    test = list()

for stock in stocks:
    stock = Stock(stock, 'SMART','USD')
    contract = ib.qualifyContracts(stock)
    test.append(ib.reqMktData(contract[0],snapshot=True))
    ib.sleep(15)

for stock in test:
    f = open('tvix-price.csv','w')
    f.write(str(stock.last))
    f.close()
```

Comment: Did you mean to indent the `for` loops inside the `while` loop? Currently you are just setting `stocks` and `test` over and over again and never even getting to the `for` loops.

Comment: ok. makes sense I was wondering if the for loop should be indented.

Comment: Python is special. Because code should be readable (if you *import this* in a python IDE you’ll see that *Readability counts* is one of the main philosophies behind it) indentation has meaning to compound statements. This works nicely with another philosophy *flat is better than nested* because indentation discourages doing too deep logic in code. https://docs.python.org/3.0/reference/compound_stmts.html?highlight=indent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of your code wasn't indented correctly, and you put the wrong part in the loop.
You should have done:

```
import csv
from ib_insync import *

stocks = ['TVIX']
while True:
    test = list()

    for stock in stocks:
        stock = Stock(stock, 'SMART','USD')
        contract = ib.qualifyContracts(stock)
        test.append(ib.reqMktData(contract[0],snapshot=True))
        ib.sleep(15)

    for stock in test:
        f = open('tvix-price.csv','w')
        f.write(str(stock.last))

        f.close()
```

The while True loop only repeats the indented section. As part of your code was not indented beyond the loop, it wasn't run.
Hope this helps.